# How to create one Controller which returns same Model to arbitrary view (HTML-Form or Ajax)?

Tags: spring-mvc

In my classic understanding of the MVC pattern the controller doesn't have to know any implementation details of the view. I want to have a controller which gets triggered by an event (a `@RequestMapping`) and returns a model. It's up to the view how to present the Model.

The concret use case is adding an item into a shopping cart. I have two views, a simple HTML view and a richer Ajax-View. In my dream scenario both views make a request to the identical URI and hit the only method in my Controller:

```
@Controller
public class ShoppingCartController {

    @RequestMapping("/add")
    public String addItem(@RequestParam String itemId, Model model) {
        // …
        model.add(shoppingCart);
        return "cart";
    }

}
```

My Ajax view sends a request to /add?itemId=abc and would get ideally the model in JSON. My HTML view sends to the same request and renders the model into a JSP.

My current approach is implementing a second method in the controller which calls `addItem()` and returns the JSON:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", headers="x-requested-with=XMLHttpRequest")
public @ResponseBody ShoppingCart addItemByAjax(@RequestParam String itemId, Model model) {
    addItem(itemId, model);
    return model.asMap().get("shoppingCart");
}
```

I don't really like that idea of decorating every controller with a view dependent Model adapter. Is there are more generic way to serve the view with the approriate presentation of the model? I want to have only one method in my controller which sends the model to any view. Of course there must exist somewhere on the stack a handler which decides to serve the model as JSON if some condition is true (let's say x-requested-with=XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` configured with a `MappingJackson2JsonView` as default view seems to help. It was more trial and error than reading documentation. Plus for me it reads not so intuitiv setting the default view to JSON. And I wonder how you guys solved this common use case before Spring 3.2.

Comment: `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` has been around since Spring 3.0 and before that a lot of projects used `RESTeasy` which is an implementation of [JSR 311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311) (Java API for RESTful Web Services) which also supported [Content Negotiaion](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/2.0.0.GA/userguide/html/JAX-RS_Content_Negotiation.html) via JAXB MessageBodyWriters. Spring 3 removed a great deal of this pain and Spring 3.2 even more so. See [latest docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multiple-representations).