# Spring MVC Send HTML & JSON

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc

I need to develop an web application in spring mvc, which can respond to client in html, json and xml by taking input parameters, how can I design this using spring mvc, I know using @ResponseBody I can get xml or json response, but how to get html response, I need to give different methods for html and json or with same method it is possible?

> Example:
> http://blip.tv/file/6213507?skin=json - Gives json o/p
>
> http://blip.tv/file/6213507?skin=api  - Gives xml o/p
>
> http://blip.tv/file/6213507           - Gives html o/p

Comment: I asked a similar question and [answered it myself][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076682/how-to-create-one-control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a great example on doing this using [ContentNegotiatingViewResolver](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-mvc-contentnegotiatingviewresolver-example/)

Comment: is this emerging as a sort-of standard way to do this? It looks so

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own view class by extending `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView`

And in this class override following method -

```
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map model,
                                   HttpServletRequest request,
                                   HttpServletResponse response)
                            throws Exception
```

And set content type like `response.setContentType("text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");`
as per `skin` parameter